# Bluetooth audio plays slower after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: audio, catalina, bluetooth

I have an early 2015 Macbook Air that I connect to a Panasonic SC-PMX92 audio system via bluetooth.
I recently upgraded the OS from Yosemite to Catalina and since the upgrade the audio playback on the audio system is broken.

Initially I thought that the issue was just bad latency, but after some more investigation it looks like somehow the sample rate has been "lost in translation" - I can play a 1kHz test tone (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FBijeNg_Gs&t=15s) and the tone out the speakers is ~919 Hz (tested using a chromatic tuner). 44.1 kHz / 48 kHz * 1 kHz = 918.75 Hz. Coincidence, I think not!

The audio system supports AAC and the bluetooth icon indicates it is using AAC.

What I have tried:

- Reset the SMC
- Set "Enable AAC codec" = 0; (this didn't appear to have any effect)
- Forget all bluetooth devices and reset the bluetooth module

**EDIT**
Looking at Audio MIDI Setup I can see the format is only 48 kHz, which is strange because the system supports up to 192 kHz. I'm still not sure if this is a Catalina error or an error with the audio system, however the audio system doesn't have any firmware updates and the output worked in Yosemite (but I don't have any before pictures)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for BT devices but it does for everything else - Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup [show audio devices, Cmd/1] Select your device & the Output tab. Check what formats are available… sometimes toggling one to the other 48-44 [& back] is enough to just jog its elbow.

Comment: @Tetsujin 48000 Hz is the only option 

Comment: Which is doubly-weird as it appears to be playing back 48k sound at 44.1 :\ I'd be tempted to see if Panasonic have anything to say about it. Maybe test on a different user account on the Mac, or see if it works in safe mode, see if some 3rd party structure is messing with it

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if there's a firmware update for the Panasonic I can load